# Database Windows Phone 7 (not local)

Tags: database, windows-phone

I'm new here, first of all sorry for my english.

Well I'm trying to develop a WindowsPhone app, and i need it to work with a database server (not local), I have extensively searched for through the internet and can't understand how to do so. Even on MSDN they only explain how to work with local databases, and it doesn't explain very well either.

Can some one post something like a tutorial or similar? Like step by step.

I'm used to programming, I'm not new at this, also I know some basics about C# and xaml, but I do am new to mobile apps development.

Please I need help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here are some links that will help you:

- [OData client for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521146%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [Consuming OData with MVVM for Windows Phone](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Consuming-OData-with-MVVM-66540635)
- [WCF Data Services/Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838239%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [Database using WCF for Windows Phone](http://studentguru.gr/b/dt008/archive/2010/12/02/querying-a-database-on-windows-phone-7-using-wcf.aspx)

Enjoy!